# Shiny.io out of memory

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to create an interactive map using the shiny web application in R. After creating and deploying the app to my shiny.io account, the URL to the application actually does not display the map but only shows the side panel and main panel. After about 15 seconds of opening the web page, it will say disconnected from the server.

Here is the link to the shint app: https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/application/2621249

Here is the log of shiny.io:

```
2020-07-29T02:44:56.206023+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.2, released 2017/09/15
2020-07-29T02:44:56.206025+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
2020-07-29T02:44:56.206025+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Path to PROJ shared files: (autodetected)
2020-07-29T02:44:56.206025+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Linking to sp version:1.4-2
2020-07-29T02:44:56.223035+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:
2020-07-29T02:44:56.222229+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.223036+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.222232+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Attaching package: ‘ggplot2’
2020-07-29T02:44:56.222232+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.223037+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:     mpg
2020-07-29T02:44:56.223037+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.753980+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.753982+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Attaching package: ‘plotly’
2020-07-29T02:44:56.753983+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754327+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754641+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:     filter
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754640+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754328+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754639+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754949+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754329+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:     last_plot
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754950+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754950+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:     layout
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772112+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772476+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772114+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772476+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754329+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772477+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754641+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772113+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2020-07-29T02:44:56.754948+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772808+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772808+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772809+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772477+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:     filter, lag
2020-07-29T02:44:56.772809+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:45:08.209263+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: trying URL 'https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip'
2020-07-29T02:45:08.390900+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: downloaded 3.2 MB
2020-07-29T02:45:08.390902+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-29T02:45:08.459882+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
2020-07-29T02:45:08.459895+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Source: "/srv/connect/apps/USMapWithCountyPolygon/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp", layer: "cb_2018_us_state_500k"
2020-07-29T02:45:08.459896+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: with 56 features
2020-07-29T02:45:08.459896+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: It has 9 fields
2020-07-29T02:45:08.459908+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Integer64 fields read as doubles:  ALAND AWATER 
2020-07-29T02:45:11.681534+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Warning: `arrange_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0.
2020-07-29T02:45:11.681536+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Please use `arrange()` instead.
2020-07-29T02:45:11.681537+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: See vignette('programming') for more help
2020-07-29T02:45:11.681538+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
2020-07-29T02:45:11.681538+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
2020-07-29T02:45:31.135291+00:00 shinyapps[system]: Out of memory!
```

The last line says that the shinyapps system is Out of memory. What should I do in this case to fix it?

Comment: How big are these files you're downloading. There's probably a memory limit on shiny.io.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try increasing the memory size, either using the dashboard or using the following code.
`rsconnect::configureApp("APPNAME", size="xlarge")`

By default shinyapp.io apps have 1024MB, xlarge bumps that up to 2048MB. The largest is xxxlarge with 8192MB.

I'm assuming the app works correctly when run locally. When running locally you could use Task Manager or similar to view your apps memory usage. You may need to optimise your apps memory usage.